# typescript request-promise no overload matches this call

Tags: node.js, typescript, request-promise

The below code is failing on my request-promise,
i already tried cleaning node_modules and installing the dependecies again

```
 try {
        const response = await request(reqOptions) // Error Highlighting `reqOptions`;
        this.products = _.concat(this.products, response.products);
        if(response.nextPage){
          return this.getProductsCatalog(response.nextPage);
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.products);
        }
      } catch(err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
```

error

> No overload matches this call.
>     Overload 1 of 3, '(uri: string, options?: RequestPromiseOptions, callback?: RequestCallback): RequestPromise', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ headers: { 'content-type': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>     Overload 2 of 3, '(uri: string, callback?: RequestCallback): RequestPromise', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ headers: { 'content-type': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>     Overload 3 of 3, '(options: (UriOptions & RequestPromiseOptions) | (UrlOptions & RequestPromiseOptions), callback?: RequestCallback): RequestPromise<...>', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type '{ headers: { 'content-type': string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(UriOptions & RequestPromiseOptions) | (UrlOptions & RequestPromiseOptions)'.
>         Type '{ headers: { 'content-type': string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'UrlOptions & RequestPromiseOptions'.
>           Property 'url' is missing in type '{ headers: { 'content-type': string; };

Whole function

```
  async getProductsCatalog(url: string): Promise<Product[]>{
    if(url === null) {
      this.products = [];;
      return this.sendGetRequest('/v1/catalog/products', 
        {
          pageSize: 40
        }
      )
      .then((res) => JSON.parse(res))
      .then((res) => {
        const response: ProductCatalogResponse = res;
        this.products = _.concat(this.products, response.products)
        if(response.nextPage) {
          return this.getProductsCatalog(response.nextPage);
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.products);
        }
      });
    } else {
      let reqOptions = {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      };

      this.visitRequest(reqOptions, 'GET', url, {pageSize: 40}, false)
      try {
        const response = await request(reqOptions);
        this.products = _.concat(this.products, response.products);
        if(response.nextPage){
          return this.getProductsCatalog(response.nextPage);
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.products);
        }
      } catch(err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Is this not clear enough - `Property 'url' is missing in type '{ headers: { 'content-type': string; };`? It looks like you should specify the url as the first parameter or include it in the request options.